# XSLT remove unwanted elements

Tags: xml

I have XML

```
<getInquiryAboutListReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<inquiryAbouts>
<inquiryAbout>
<code>Code</code>
<nameKk>Something</nameKk>
<nameRu>Something</nameRu>
<documents xsi:nil="true"/>
</inquiryAbout>
</inquiryAbouts>
</getInquiryAboutListReturn>
```

And I want to process it with XSLT to copy all XML

*How could I copy all XML without `<documents xsi:nil="true"/>` or without xsi:nil="true"?*

Desired output XML

```
<getInquiryAboutListReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<inquiryAbouts>
<inquiryAbout>
<code>Code</code>
<nameKk>Something</nameKk>
<nameRu>Something</nameRu>
</inquiryAbout>
</inquiryAbouts>
</getInquiryAboutListReturn>
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it appears to relate programming. It may be on topic for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This simple XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- TEMPLATE #1 -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- TEMPLATE #2 -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@xsi:nil = 'true']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to the OP's source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<getInquiryAboutListReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <inquiryAbouts>
    <inquiryAbout>
      <code>Code</code>
      <nameKk>Something</nameKk>
      <nameRu>Something</nameRu>
      <documents xsi:nil="true"/>
    </inquiryAbout>
  </inquiryAbouts>
</getInquiryAboutListReturn>
```

**...produces the expected result XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<getInquiryAboutListReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <inquiryAbouts>
    <inquiryAbout>
      <code>Code</code>
      <nameKk>Something</nameKk>
      <nameRu>Something</nameRu>
    </inquiryAbout>
  </inquiryAbouts>
</getInquiryAboutListReturn>
```

**EXPLANATION:**

1. The first template -- the [Identity Template](http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=492) -- copies all nodes and attributes from the source XML document as-is.
2. The second template, which matches all elements with the specified, namespaced attribute equalling "true", effectively removes those elements.

Comment: can you explain what "Identity Template" means? the link seems to be outdated